# What are the benefits of case sharing via locations vs. case sharing groups

Tags: commcare

I am considering different case sharing configurations for my app, and am wondering what the main differences are between case sharing via [locations/organizations](https://confluence.dimagi.com/display/commcarepublic/Case+Sharing+using+Organizations) versus [case sharing groups](https://confluence.dimagi.com/display/commcarepublic/Case+Sharing).

Is the benefit of locations/organizations just the hierarchy of case visibility, or are there other benefits?

If I need the hierarchy, it's clear that locations is the best feature, but what if I don't need the hierarchy? Is there any benefit to using locations and setting up a flat structure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The organizations feature is meant to map to organization hierarchies, and is useful for larger projects where you may have, for instance, district managers who oversee a subset of the project.  There is also a [feature](https://confluence.dimagi.com/display/commcarepublic/Location-Based+Data+Access+and+User+Editing+Restrictions) which allows you to grant web users access restricted to only data from their section of the organization hierarchy.

If your project doesn't have any sort of hierarchical structure, and you're specifically looking for a solution for case-sharing, then either locations or groups should work.  Groups are also a little simpler to set up.